How to generalise the argument in Chap. 1 in Baby Rudin to show that these sets $A$ and $B$ have no largest and smallest elements, respectively?
Let $n$ be a positive integer that is NOT a perfect square, and let the sets $A$ and $B$ be defined as follows:
$$
A := \left\{ p \in \mathbb{Q} \colon p > 0, p^2 < n \right\}
$$
and
$$
B := \left\{ p \in \mathbb{Q} \colon p > 0, p^2 > n \right\}.
$$
Then how to show that the set $A$ has no largest element and $B$ has no smallest element?
The case whan $n = 2$ has been discussed just after Example 1.1, in Chap. 1, in the book Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition, where for each positive rational number $p$, there is defined the number $q$ as follows:
$$
q := p - \frac{p^2-2}{p+2} = \frac{2p+2}{p+2}.
$$
Then it can be easily shown that, if $p \in A$, then $q \in A$ also and $q > p$, whereas if $p \in B$, then $q \in B$ also and $q < p$.
How to generalise this argument to tackle the case when $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer that is not a perfect square?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_method

If I understand what you are asking, this might be an approach.
Generalize as follows:
$$
q=p-\frac{p^{2}-n}{p+n}=\frac{np+n}{p+n}
$$
Then we obtain
$$
q^{2}=\frac{n^{2}p^{2}+2pn^{2}+n^{2}}{\left(p+n\right)^{2}}.
$$
Continuing with the algebra
$$
q^{2}-n=\frac{n^{2}p^{2}+2pn^{2}+n^{2}}{\left(p+n\right)^{2}}-n
$$
$$
q^{2}-n=\frac{n^{2}p^{2}+2pn^{2}+n^{2}-np^{2}-2n^{2}p-n^{3}}{\left(p+n\right)^{2}}
$$
$$
q^{2}-n=\frac{n^{2}p^{2}+n^{2}-np^{2}-n^{3}}{\left(p+n\right)^{2}}
$$
$$
q^{2}-n=\frac{\left(n^{2}-n\right)\left(p^{2}-n\right)}{\left(p+n\right)^{2}}
$$
From this point on, I believe similar arguments apply as in the case $n=2$.

thank you for your answer.
